# Jenkins - trigger post-build action based on parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job set up that builds my iOS Xcode project and archives the resulting IPA file. In addition, I have also installed the Testflight plugin to upload the IPA file as a post-build action. That's all working fine, and my question is this...is there a way to only trigger that post-build action based on the result of a boolean build parameter. There are certain cases where I need to be able to build an IPA and I don't want it to be uploaded to Testflight. If I could just add a checkbox at the start of the build that determines whether or not to upload to Testflight that would be ideal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Flexible Publish plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) supports [Run Conditions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin). Never tried it myself, but heard good things about it from others.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind setting up a separate Jenkins job to do the IPA file upload, you could use the [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Comment: Downvoting because the Parameterized Trigger plugin doesn't allow you to conditionally trigger builds in the way requested.